# Is it possible copy text from vim to a system buffer?

Tags: vim

I want to copy text from vim, eg. by selecting in `visual mode`, then `ctrl+insert` and I'd like to have the copied text in system buffer, so I can paste it anywhere I like with eg `ctrl+v`. Is it possible somehow?

Problem arises when I need to copy long text from vim window to buffer. I cannot simply select it all with a mouse and then copy it, because the text doesn't fit in the window.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. Vim has references to the system clipboards as registers, which you can use like any other registers.

The main clipboard is `*`, so you can highlight in visual mode, then type `"*y`. If you're using X11 you can copy to the X11 buffer using the `+` register. Lastly, you can reassign the default register to the clipboard register with `:set clipboard=unnamed`. If you do this then any copies, yanks, or kills will automatically go to the system clipboard without you manually specifying the register first.

Comment: It worked first time after I rebooted my PC. But after that when I've used console buffer, system buffer, etc, they seems to have mixed up. So now when I do `"*y`, text doesn't go to system buffer. But X11 buffer `+` still working fine. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 2):

The visual selection (<kbd>v</kbd>, <kbd>V</kbd>, or <kbd>CTRL+V</kbd>) can automatically be copied to the X11 selection (* buffer).

In non-gui mode the clipboard option controls this (only supported if +xterm_clipboard appears when you type `vim --version`).  In GUI mode `guioptions` controls it.

This makes all Visual mode selections automatically go to the X11 primary selection:

```
set clipboard+=autoselect<br>
set guioptions+=a
```

This turns it off:

```
set clipboard-=autoselect<br>
set guioptions-=a
```

See :`help 'clipboard'`
(single quotes required).

Answer (score 0):

On OS X you can use `pbcopy`/`pbpaste` command-line tools to achieve that.

For instance, to copy the current line, run:

```
:.!pbcopy "Copy current line clipboard
```

To copy the whole file:

```
:!echo "%:p" | pbcopy
```

Or to copy selected text (using visual mode via: <kbd>v</kbd>/<kbd>V</kbd>), type `!pbcopy` after selecting text, so it becomes: `:'<,'>!pbcopy`, so it'll copy the text into the Clipboard.

See: [Mac OS X clipboard sharing](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Mac_OS_X_clipboard_sharing)

For Linux, use `xclip`, `gpm` or [something similar](https://stackoverflow.com/q/749544/55075).